# Does overriding in swift replace or modify the current implementation of the properties and methods of the superclass? Swift

Tags: swift

Does overriding in swift replace or modify the current implementation of the properties and methods of the superclass? After experimenting with code I observed that overriden methods in swift do not modify the existing methods in the superclass. I'm assuming it's similar to dynamic binding in java. computed properties that override stored properties on the other hand seem to modify the property of the superclass.From the code below you can see that the new value 87 is printed instead of 0.0 even though super is called, while this is not true when calling methods. I wanted to confirm if my observation is true or if there is another reason behind this.

```
class Vehicle {
var currentSpeed: Double = 0.0
var cuc: Double = 0.0


var description: String {
    return "traveling at \(currentSpeed) miles per hour"
}

func makeNoise() {
    // do nothing - an arbitrary vehicle doesn't necessarily
   // make a noise
}
}

class Car: Vehicle {
var gear = 1
   override var currentSpeed: Double {
    didSet {
       print(super.currentSpeed)
    }
}
//override var currentSpeed: Double = 56
override var description: String {
    return super.description + " in gear \(gear)"
}
}
var car = Car()
car.currentSpeed = 87
print(car.description)
```

This other segment of code does the opposite and produces 0 instead of 90 .

```
override var currentSpeed: Double {
set {
    super.cuc = 90
}
    get {
       return super.cuc
    }
    }
print(car.cuc)
```

Comment: Why would you expect `currentSpeed` to be `0`? `Car`'s override of it is just an override on `didSet`, it doesn't (nor can it) introduce its own storage for the property.

Comment: makes sense. Does this also mean overriden methods do not have their own storage?

Comment: Depends what you mean by storage. Properties deal with stored values on instances (usually through accessor methods). Method implementations aren't directly stored on instances, instead they're compiled as functions that take an implicit parameter for the instance that they're being called on. Although each instance of a class (indirectly) holds a vtable that maps from a given method call to the implementation to invoke (in order to allow for dynamic dispatch). A method override is achieved by changing the subclass' vtable to map to its own implementation of the given method (not super's)

Comment: And obviously each implementation of a given method (whether in super or subclass) has storage in the compiled binary (but the optimiser is free to remove them if it sees fit).

Comment: thx! I experimented with code and more and used get and set within a computed property but this time the currentSpeed changed?? I added the code to my question above.

Comment: Still prints 90 for me, as I would expect – when the superclass' `description` is called, it calls the getter for the subclass' override of `currentSpeed`, which returns the value of the `cuc` property that its setter set earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It does not. Consider when the statement would be true. I don't see any reason why it should work as you describe. You took the bad example in variables. For instance take functions. (see the move() function)

```
class Vehicle {
var currentSpeed: Double = 0.0

var description: String {
    return "traveling at \(currentSpeed) miles per hour"
}

func move() {

    // Move, every vehicle should really move...

}
}

class Car: Vehicle {
var gear = 1
   override var currentSpeed: Double {
    didSet {
       print(super.currentSpeed)
    }
}

override func move(){
       //Call super.move to call method from superclass for moving (default implemented behavior)
       super.move()
    //Car should make noise or start spinning wheels (lol funny example)
       startSpinningWheels()
       makeNoise()
}


private func makeNoise(){
//Make noise...

}

private func startSpinningWheels(){
//Start spinning wheels on vehicle...
}

//override var currentSpeed: Double = 56
override var description: String {
    return super.description + " in gear \(gear)"
}
}
```

Okay now. Wouldn't be strange if the method move() would modify the superclass behaviour? Because you know, then for example Plane would need to start spinning wheels, which is really obvious :D So the answer is BIG NO, that woud be fail to inheritance at all. You should read the whole idea about inheritance...

The thing is you can cast your current instance of object to superclass object (set Car as? Vehicle) and modify only the properties that are not declared in Car object...

let myCar = Car()

//No error here
let carAsVehicle = myCar as Vehicle

//neither here.
print(carAsVehicle.currentSpeed)

See inheritance in Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

wish happy coding and if you have any questions feel free to ask!